# Python - OpenCV - Detecting an object from the library in the video

Tags: opencv, template-matching, python

I would need to detect a specific object from the library on the video input.

There are various pictures in the library. Which should be gradually loaded and compared with the video input. If the read image from the library will match one object on the video input, the program should stop and print the output log (time required for detection, detection accuracy, etc.)

I tried to use OpenCV - Python, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED function, to detect it only on a static image (not on video) and I can't.

Can you help me?

Here is a link to a file with a library and video input.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rR9U2jkoHwbY7tW1-XXhThNahYQHAPHA?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use mobilenet model with open cv for object detection**

````
import datetime
import imutils
import numpy as np
import csv 
# from centroidtracker import CentroidTracker
from pyimagesearch.centroidtracker import CentroidTracker
protopath = "mobilenet_ss/MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt"
modelpath = "mobilenet_ss/MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel"


detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt=protopath, caffeModel=modelpath)
# detector.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_INFERENCE_ENGINE)
detector.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)


  
outputlist=[]        

CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
           "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
           "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep",
           "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]

tracker = CentroidTracker(maxDisappeared=80, maxDistance=90)


def non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh):
    try:
        if len(boxes) == 0:
            return []

        if boxes.dtype.kind == "i":
            boxes = boxes.astype("float")

        pick = []

        x1 = boxes[:, 0]
        y1 = boxes[:, 1]
        x2 = boxes[:, 2]
        y2 = boxes[:, 3]

        area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
        idxs = np.argsort(y2)

        while len(idxs) > 0:
            last = len(idxs) - 1
            i = idxs[last]
            pick.append(i)

            xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[idxs[:last]])
            yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[idxs[:last]])
            xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[idxs[:last]])
            yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[idxs[:last]])

            w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
            h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)

            overlap = (w * h) / area[idxs[:last]]

            idxs = np.delete(idxs, np.concatenate(([last],
                                                   np.where(overlap > overlapThresh)[0])))

        return boxes[pick].astype("int")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception occurred in non_max_suppression : {}".format(e))


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project_video.mp4')

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("output/output.mp4", fourcc, 5.0, (600,337))


    fps_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    fps = 0
    total_frames = 0
    lpc_count = 0
    opc_count = 0
    object_id_list = []

    
    # dtime = dict()
    # dwell_time = dict()

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
        total_frames = total_frames + 1

        (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
        #print("h,w",H,W)
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 0.007843, (W, H), 127.5)

        detector.setInput(blob)
        person_detections = detector.forward()
        rects = []
        for i in np.arange(0, person_detections.shape[2]):
            confidence = person_detections[0, 0, i, 2]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                idx = int(person_detections[0, 0, i, 1])

                person_box = person_detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
                (startX, startY, endX, endY) = person_box.astype("int")
                rects.append(person_box)

        boundingboxes = np.array(rects)
        boundingboxes = boundingboxes.astype(int)
        rects = non_max_suppression_fast(boundingboxes, 0.3)

        objects = tracker.update(rects)
        for (objectId, bbox) in objects.items():
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
            x1 = int(x1)
            y1 = int(y1)
            x2 = int(x2)
            y2 = int(y2)

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            text = "ID: {}".format(objectId)
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (x1, y1-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

            if objectId not in object_id_list:
                object_id_list.append(objectId)
                # dtime[objectId] = datetime.datetime.now()
                # dwell_time[objectId] = 0
            # else:
            #     curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            #     old_time = dtime[objectId]
            #     time_diff = curr_time - old_time
            #     dtime[objectId] = datetime.datetime.now()
            #     sec = time_diff.total_seconds()
            #     dwell_time[objectId] += sec

            # text = "{}|{}".format(objectId, int(dwell_time[objectId]))
            # cv2.putText(frame, text, (x1, y1-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        fps_end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_diff = fps_end_time - fps_start_time
        if time_diff.seconds == 0:
            fps = 0.0
        else:
            fps = (total_frames / time_diff.seconds)

        fps_text = "FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps)
        
        cv2.putText(frame, fps_text, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

        lpc_count = len(objects)
        opc_count = len(object_id_list)

        lpc_txt = "LPC: {}".format(lpc_count)
        opc_txt = "OPC: {}".format(opc_count)
        # writing to csv file  
        outputlist.append([lpc_count,opc_count])
        
            
        cv2.putText(frame, lpc_txt, (5, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        cv2.putText(frame, opc_txt, (5, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow("Application", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   

main()```

**create CentroidTracker.py file and paste the below code on CentroidTracker.py file and import CentroidTracker.py where you want to use**

    # import the necessary packages
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np


class CentroidTracker:
    def __init__(self, maxDisappeared=50, maxDistance=50):
        # initialize the next unique object ID along with two ordered
        # dictionaries used to keep track of mapping a given object
        # ID to its centroid and number of consecutive frames it has
        # been marked as "disappeared", respectively
        self.nextObjectID = 0
        self.objects = OrderedDict()
        self.disappeared = OrderedDict()
        self.bbox = OrderedDict()  # CHANGE

        # store the number of maximum consecutive frames a given
        # object is allowed to be marked as "disappeared" until we
        # need to deregister the object from tracking
        self.maxDisappeared = maxDisappeared

        # store the maximum distance between centroids to associate
        # an object -- if the distance is larger than this maximum
        # distance we'll start to mark the object as "disappeared"
        self.maxDistance = maxDistance

    def register(self, centroid, inputRect):
        # when registering an object we use the next available object
        # ID to store the centroid
        self.objects[self.nextObjectID] = centroid
        self.bbox[self.nextObjectID] = inputRect  # CHANGE
        self.disappeared[self.nextObjectID] = 0
        self.nextObjectID += 1

    def deregister(self, objectID):
        # to deregister an object ID we delete the object ID from
        # both of our respective dictionaries
        del self.objects[objectID]
        del self.disappeared[objectID]
        del self.bbox[objectID]  # CHANGE

    def update(self, rects):
        # check to see if the list of input bounding box rectangles
        # is empty
        if len(rects) == 0:
            # loop over any existing tracked objects and mark them
            # as disappeared
            for objectID in list(self.disappeared.keys()):
                self.disappeared[objectID] += 1

                # if we have reached a maximum number of consecutive
                # frames where a given object has been marked as
                # missing, deregister it
                if self.disappeared[objectID] > self.maxDisappeared:
                    self.deregister(objectID)

            # return early as there are no centroids or tracking info
            # to update
            # return self.objects
            return self.bbox

        # initialize an array of input centroids for the current frame
        inputCentroids = np.zeros((len(rects), 2), dtype="int")
        inputRects = []
        # loop over the bounding box rectangles
        for (i, (startX, startY, endX, endY)) in enumerate(rects):
            # use the bounding box coordinates to derive the centroid
            cX = int((startX + endX) / 2.0)
            cY = int((startY + endY) / 2.0)
            inputCentroids[i] = (cX, cY)
            inputRects.append(rects[i])  # CHANGE

        # if we are currently not tracking any objects take the input
        # centroids and register each of them
        if len(self.objects) == 0:
            for i in range(0, len(inputCentroids)):
                self.register(inputCentroids[i], inputRects[i])  # CHANGE

        # otherwise, are are currently tracking objects so we need to
        # try to match the input centroids to existing object
        # centroids
        else:
            # grab the set of object IDs and corresponding centroids
            objectIDs = list(self.objects.keys())
            objectCentroids = list(self.objects.values())

            # compute the distance between each pair of object
            # centroids and input centroids, respectively -- our
            # goal will be to match an input centroid to an existing
            # object centroid
            D = dist.cdist(np.array(objectCentroids), inputCentroids)

            # in order to perform this matching we must (1) find the
            # smallest value in each row and then (2) sort the row
            # indexes based on their minimum values so that the row
            # with the smallest value as at the *front* of the index
            # list
            rows = D.min(axis=1).argsort()

            # next, we perform a similar process on the columns by
            # finding the smallest value in each column and then
            # sorting using the previously computed row index list
            cols = D.argmin(axis=1)[rows]

            # in order to determine if we need to update, register,
            # or deregister an object we need to keep track of which
            # of the rows and column indexes we have already examined
            usedRows = set()
            usedCols = set()

            # loop over the combination of the (row, column) index
            # tuples
            for (row, col) in zip(rows, cols):
                # if we have already examined either the row or
                # column value before, ignore it
                if row in usedRows or col in usedCols:
                    continue

                # if the distance between centroids is greater than
                # the maximum distance, do not associate the two
                # centroids to the same object
                if D[row, col] > self.maxDistance:
                    continue

                # otherwise, grab the object ID for the current row,
                # set its new centroid, and reset the disappeared
                # counter
                objectID = objectIDs[row]
                self.objects[objectID] = inputCentroids[col]
                self.bbox[objectID] = inputRects[col]  # CHANGE
                self.disappeared[objectID] = 0

                # indicate that we have examined each of the row and
                # column indexes, respectively
                usedRows.add(row)
                usedCols.add(col)

            # compute both the row and column index we have NOT yet
            # examined
            unusedRows = set(range(0, D.shape[0])).difference(usedRows)
            unusedCols = set(range(0, D.shape[1])).difference(usedCols)

            # in the event that the number of object centroids is
            # equal or greater than the number of input centroids
            # we need to check and see if some of these objects have
            # potentially disappeared
            if D.shape[0] >= D.shape[1]:
                # loop over the unused row indexes
                for row in unusedRows:
                    # grab the object ID for the corresponding row
                    # index and increment the disappeared counter
                    objectID = objectIDs[row]
                    self.disappeared[objectID] += 1

                    # check to see if the number of consecutive
                    # frames the object has been marked "disappeared"
                    # for warrants deregistering the object
                    if self.disappeared[objectID] > self.maxDisappeared:
                        self.deregister(objectID)

            # otherwise, if the number of input centroids is greater
            # than the number of existing object centroids we need to
            # register each new input centroid as a trackable object
            else:
                for col in unusedCols:
                    self.register(inputCentroids[col], inputRects[col])

        # return the set of trackable objects
        # return self.objects
        return self.bbox
````

Comment: Thanks for the solution offered but: I didn't run it because I can't find pyimagesearch / centroidtracker.

Otherwise, I would need to extract the image from lib, and if it is not on the input, let the next one be selected. Until the right one is found. Which matches video = lib.

I take other things that are on the video only as trash that I am not interested in.